# Chrome Extension: In Tabs doc don't exist this "chrome.tabs.getSelected" but I see aniway in examples

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension, browser-tab

as title I can't able find this method into the Api -> Tabs... 
Way and where?
Thanks'

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was [deprecated in Chrome 16](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html#16). The correct way is to use [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) with `active:true` and `lastFocusedWindow:true`.

```
// Get the current active tab in the lastly focused window
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function(tabs) {
    // and use that tab to fill in out title and url
    var tab = tabs[0];
    run({
        url: tab.url,
        description: tab.title
    });
});
```

Comment: How can I access to DOM for the current/last selected tab? i would like to access it with jquery, TIA.

Answer (score 2):

It was removed. Use [chrome.tabs.query](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-query) instead.

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected

It's a deprecated method, but you can still use it.

```js
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
  var url = tab.url;
});
```